# std::is_swappable_v is false on a swappable class template

Tags: c++, c++17, swap, type-traits, std

I'm trying to write a swappable class template, `S<T>`. I'd like `S<T>` and
`S<T&>` to be swappable if `T` is swappable (e.g. `S<int>` should be swappable
with `S<int&>`). So I went for something like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace n {

template <typename T>
struct S {};

// Overload #1
template <typename T, typename U>
void swap(S<T>&, S<U>&) {}

// Overload #2
// template <typename T>
// void swap(S<T>&, S<T>&) {}

}  // namespace n

int main() {
    n::S<int> sInt;
    swap(sInt, sInt);
    // static_assert(std::is_swappable_v<decltype(sInt)>);
    //               ^ assertion fails unless I uncomment #2

    n::S<int&> sIntRef;
    swap(sInt, sIntRef);
    static_assert(
        std::is_swappable_with_v<decltype(sInt)&, decltype(sIntRef)&>);
    //  ^ assertion evaluates the way I expect
}
```

As you can see above, `is_swappable_v<n::S<int>>` is `false` even though the
call to `swap(sInt, sInt)` compiles. In order for `is_swappable_v<n::S<int>>`
to evaluate to `true`, I need to uncomment overload `#2` for `swap`.

Am I doing anything wrong or is type trait `std::is_swappable` actually
supposed to work this way?

Comment: Your example seems to compile on GCC and clang and fails only on MSVC. I guess it is MSVC. EDIT: Ouch, with uncommented first `static_assert`, all do fail. bug? https://godbolt.org/z/v6jWW4TPW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `swap(sInt, sInt)` doesn't actually perform a [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) because [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) isn't visible (through `using std::swap;`).

When you do have it:

```cpp
int main() {
    n::S<int> sInt;

    using std::swap;
    swap(sInt, sInt);
}
```

it doesn't compile, so your type isn't actually swappable with itself.

The reason for this is that there are two possible overloads:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
void n::swap(S<T>&, S<U>&);
// with T = int, S = int

template <typename T>
void std::swap(T&, T&);
// with T = n::S<int>
```

The first one would be better because each argument is more specialized.
The second one would be better because both arguments are the same and they come from the same template argument.

Since they are both better in different ways, it makes it an ambiguous call.

When you add your second template overload:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void n::swap(S<T>&, S<T>&);
// with T = int
```

This is better than the first `n::swap` because of the repeated argument, and better than `std::swap` because it's more specialized, so it is chosen unambiguously.